# Why does ContentControl.insertOoxml(original_content_control_ooxml) seem to create new unvisible content controls?

Tags: office-js

I want to be able to hide/unhide contents of some content controls. For this, I get ooxml of the content, save and load using customXmlParts, and `insertOoxml()` back.

Currently I can hide and unhide once. On the second hide attempt, `context.document.contentControls.getByTitle()` gives me twice the number of content controls i see on the screen. Half of the id's are new. When I try to `getOoxml()` of these, the system produces an error with  `errorLocation` of `ContentControlCollection.getItem`.

I promisified Office 2013 apis as follows:

```
function cxpAddCustomXmlPartAsync(xml): 
  Promise<Office.AsyncResult<Office.CustomXmlPart>>{
  return new Promise((resolve)=>{
    Office.context.document.customXmlParts.addAsync(xml, (asyncResult)=>{
      resolve(asyncResult);
    })
  });
}

function cxpGetCustomXmlPartByIdAsync(id): 
  Promise<Office.AsyncResult<Office.CustomXmlPart>> {
  return new Promise((resolve)=>{
    Office.context.document.customXmlParts.getByIdAsync(id, 
      (result: Office.AsyncResult<Office.CustomXmlPart>)=>{
        resolve(result)
      })
  });
}

function cxpDeleteXmlPartAsync(part:Office.CustomXmlPart){
  return new Promise((resolve)=>{
    part.deleteAsync((result: Office.AsyncResult<void>)=>{
      resolve(result)
    });
  });
}

function cxpGetXmlAsync(part: Office.CustomXmlPart):
  Promise<Office.AsyncResult<string>> {
  return new Promise((resolve)=>{
    part.getXmlAsync((result)=>{
      resolve(result);
    });
  });
}
```

And following function tries to hide/unhide twice. On the second iteration, I get the error on the line with `//*`.

```
const customXmlIds = {};
export async function run() {
  return Word.run(async context => {
    for (let iteration=0;iteration<2;iteration++){
      // get a list of all content controls with title "My Title"
      let ccs = context.document.contentControls.getByTitle("My Title"); 
      ccs.load("id");
      await context.sync();
      write(JSON.stringify(ccs));

      // save contents of all the matching content controls
      for(let i=0; i <ccs.items.length; i++){
        const ooxmlObj = ccs.items[i].getOoxml(); // *
        await context.sync();

        const ooxml = ooxmlObj.value; 
        ccs.items[i].insertText("-", "Replace");
        const result = await cxpAddCustomXmlPartAsync(ooxml);
        customXmlIds[ccs.items[i].id] = result.value.id
        await context.sync()
      }


      // get a list of all content controls with title "My Title"
      ccs = context.document.contentControls.getByTitle("My Title");
      ccs.load("id");
      await context.sync();

      // load back content control data
      for(let i=0; i <ccs.items.length; i++){
        const xmlPartId = customXmlIds[ccs.items[i].id];
        const partResult = await cxpGetCustomXmlPartByIdAsync(xmlPartId);
        const xmlResult = await cxpGetXmlAsync(partResult.value);
        ccs.items[i].insertOoxml(xmlResult.value,"Replace");
        write(JSON.stringify(xmlResult))
        await context.sync();
        const deleteResult = await cxpDeleteXmlPartAsync(partResult.value);
        delete customXmlIds[xmlPartId];
      }
  }
  });
}
```

Comment: I can reproduce. It is the presence of the `insertOoxml` line in the last `for` loop that causes the error. If I add any line that references `ccs` (like `console.log(ccs);` just above your last `for` loop, the error comes at that line on the second iteration. So, the `ccs` collection is corrupted when the `insertOoxml` line runs on the first iteration. This looks like a bug. I think you should raise this as an issue at the office-js repo: [office-js issues](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a fun case, and to some degree, what you describe is by design and not been handled properly in your code. In fact, I  doubt that's what you want to do. Let me explain.

The root of the issue is that by doing a ccs.items[i].getOoxml() you are actually getting the OOXML of the content control, including the actual content control. so that's why when you save and then replace the cc content with  that OOXML you are actually inserting a content control within a content control, that's why you end up doubling the size of the content controls each time ! :)  Hopefully this is not confusing...

I think what you really want is to OOXML-ize is what's inside the content control, right? I am assuming based on your code sample that hiding on this context means not the entire content control, but you want an empty content control (with a "-") instead, correct?

If that's the case you need to get the OOXML of the "content" of the content control. this is how you do it:

```
 const ooxmlObj = ccs.items[i]
        .getRange("start")
        .expandTo(ccs.items[i].getRange("end"))
        .getOoxml();
```

that simple instruction will get you just the inner of the content control, thats the OOXML you need to store and then replace.

Please check out a working sample here (scriptlab) https://gist.github.com/JuaneloJuanelo/4a78ab47b7df9594bc7d097842166cbf

also i am not sure why you are saving this as an XML Part... i used an array on my sample, then you can use the settings object to persist the array. up to you where you want to store the temp OOXMLs.

happy coding!

Comment: Ooxml of the control and its contents are different. This makes sense. Thanks. The parts I am hiding can include images and so may be big in size. Somehow I thought there would be a size limit when persisting using the settings object. Is this wrong?

Comment: yes, if I  remember correctly you cannot store more than 2MB on settings. so xml parts is your best bet for those cases.